# Can algorithm using Java AtomicStampedReference can be considered non-blocking?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, data-structures, concurrency

I'm trying to implement **non-blocking binary search tree** as described [here](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~ruppert/podc10.pdf) using Java. This algorithm is based on single-world CAS but:

> The state and info
>   fields are stored together in a CAS object. Thus, an internal
>   node uses four words of memory.

I decided to use **AtomicStampedReference** to store this data. The problem is that it

> maintains stamped references by creating internal objects representing "boxed" [reference, integer] pairs.

Internal implementation of this structure:

```
public boolean compareAndSet(V   expectedReference,
                             V   newReference,
                             int expectedStamp,
                             int newStamp) {
    Pair<V> current = pair;
    return
        expectedReference == current.reference &&
        expectedStamp == current.stamp &&
        ((newReference == current.reference &&
          newStamp == current.stamp) ||
         casPair(current, Pair.of(newReference, newStamp)));
}
```

Pair defined as:

```
private static class Pair<T> {
    final T reference;
    final int stamp;
    private Pair(T reference, int stamp) {
        this.reference = reference;
        this.stamp = stamp;
    }
    static <T> Pair<T> of(T reference, int stamp) {
        return new Pair<T>(reference, stamp);
    }
}
```

Is this implementation still non-blocking?

And the extra question: what's making this **compareAndSet** operation atomic ?

Comment: You are mainly asking about specific semantics of Java code, so the question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow.  But you'll probably have to clarify some things to get a good answer over at SO.  (1) what is `casPair()`? (2) You say at the top you are using `AtomicStampedReference` but then don't mention it anywhere in the code, (3) its not clear why you use the word "problem" before the second quote, why is it problematic that an AtomicStampedReference atomically maintains a boxed pair?

Comment: There may be a question about data structures here, but as this question stands, it's about how a Java library behaves, so it's squarely on the side of being a programming question, not a computer science question. Therefore I've migrated this question to [so].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What do we call a lock-free algorithm?

**[Disclaimer]** Until I wrote this explicitly, my statements is about algorithms in general, not considering Java CAS implementation.

Yes, in my opinion algorithm based on CAS can be considered lock-free. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock-free) provides definition of lock-free algorithm:

> In computer science, a **non-blocking** algorithm ensures that threads competing for a shared resource do not have their execution indefinitely postponed by mutual exclusion. A non-blocking algorithm is **lock-free** if there is guaranteed system-wide progress regardless of scheduling;
>
> ...
>
> In modern usage, therefore, an algorithm is **non-blocking** if the suspension of one or more threads will not stop the potential progress of the remaining threads.

Let's take a look over CAS-based algorithm in that context [saying *algorithm* I mean setting variable using CAS instruction with while loop]:

Question one: **Is CAS-based algorithm non-blocking?** At each particular moment of time, there is one thread that will successfully CAS variable. If we suspend one of them, one of remaining will succeed instead. Thus, the algorithm satisfies the definition I quoted and the answer is yes.

Question two: **Is CAS-based algorithm lock-free?** I think the answer is yes again, because system-wide, but not per-thread progress (each thread will eventually succeed cas-ing variable) is guaranteed.

**Now, let's consider CAS-based algorithms implemented in Java using `AtomicXXX` classes and CAS operations on its objects.** Technically, there is no guarantee of lock-free-ness of such algorithms because of possible external influences from JVM side:

```
public class Entity {
    static {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (getClass().getClassLoader()){
                    try {
                        getClass().getClassLoader().wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicReference v = new AtomicReference(new Object());
        Object var = null;
        Object somenew;
        do {
            var = v.get();
            somenew = new Object();
        } while(!v.compareAndSet(var, somenew));
    }

}
```

The algorithm implemented in `main()` is lock-free but due to the class loader's monitor not being notified ever, there will be no system-wide progress. **So, what the hell I just wrote?** The statement that cas-based algorithms is lock-free in Java just because of the fact they are cas-based is wrong.

### CAS instruction atomicity

CAS instruction is atomic by its definition. **In most modern CPU** this instruction is supported, i.e. does what we expect it to do and does it atomically. Let's say, CPU vendor guarantees that CPU supports atomic CAS.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) quote:

> Compare-and-Swap (and Compare-and-Swap-Double) has been an integral part of the IBM 370 (and all successor) architectures since 1970.
>
> As of 2013, most multiprocessor architectures support CAS in hardware.

Some proofs from JDK:

`AtomicInteger.compareAndSet()` [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet%28int,%20int%29) states:

> **Atomically** sets the value to the given updated value if the current value == the expected value.

Same can be found on `AtomicXXX` classes, you can easily find it, so doesn't worth copypasting here.

Now, let's consider `AtomicStampedReference.compareAndSet()`. Its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicStampedReference.html#compareAndSet%28V,%20V,%20int,%20int%29) says:

> **Atomically sets the value** of both the reference and stamp to the given update values if the current reference is == to the expected reference and the current stamp is equal to the expected stamp.

I think from that javadoc we cannot conclude that the whole operation is atomic, it just **sets** the value atomically, so either both stamp and reference are set, or none of them as CAS fails.

Comment: Question two: but the call method compareAndSet() is also suggested to be atomic while it consist of multiple operations.

Comment: @atok `compareAndSet()` call is atomic in Java. Can you please explain the concern caused you to comment more clearly?

Comment: My concern is caused by the difference between the low-level CAS instruction and implementation of CAS functionality in the AtomicStampedReference structure. Method compareAndSet() of that structure does not call CAS instruction directly - it runs plain-old Java code I included in the question.

Comment: @Dukeling, I think post looks better when the text is indented on the list numbers, not item starts. So if you do not mind, can you please revert indentation update?

Comment: @atok Well, you're right about that concern. I'll update my post.

Comment: @AlexeyMalev Stack Exchange clearly doesn't want you to do it that way, because then the numbering is `1.` for all items. If you prefer that indentation (although I can't see why you would), you should probably use non-numeric formatting like `1)` for example, or bullets - `-`.

Comment: @Dukeling ok, but still, can you please revert so I can change list markers only?

Comment: @atok I have reviewed and updated my answer. Please reconsider whether you still accept it. Btw, big thanks to my friend and colleague for reviewing the post and criticism.